# Skipping For loop in Python

Tags: python

Inside my code it has been skipping the for iteration
Heres the code i  have been using

```
 print ("part two")
varZ = varA - 0.5
varY = firstNumber / varZ

for varZ in list(reversed(range(firstNumber, 0))):
    print ("part three")
    varY = firstNumber / varZ
    if (varY - int(varY) == 0):
        print ("part four")
        break

    else:
        varZ = varZ - 1
        print ("part five")

print("Part six, Your answer is...", int(varZ))
```

Thanks for the help!
P.s the output is

```
Your number sir? 27
Calculating...
13.5
part two
Part six, Your answer is... 13
```

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

`range(firstNumber, 0)` is almost certainly empty, unless you're expecting a negative firstNumber. It's unclear what you're trying to do here; if you're trying to iterate over something like `[5,4,3,2,1,0]`, you should use `range(5, 0, -1)`. [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) for more info

Comment: It will be empty in any case where firstNumber is not >= 1. To generate an iterable that yields the numbers in descending order you also need to define the step: `range(firstNumber, 0, -1)`

Comment: yeah, it wasn't clear to me whether the poster was expecting a negative firstNumber, was confused about the range syntax and was trying to iterate in reverse with the `reversed` call, or whether he thought that switching the arguments in range would reverse the iterator or something. I'll maybe add some clarification to the answer

Answer (score 0):

`range(firstNumber, 0)` is going to be an empty list (unless `firstNumber` is negative).  The default increment is 1.  If you get rid of the `0`, then the `range` expression will count up from `0` to `firstNumber-1`.  I'm not sure if you want to start with `firstNumber` or `firstNumber-1`, so I'll use `n` in this example:

```
for x in list(reversed(range(n))):
```

You can simplify this to:

```
for x in reversed(range(n)):
```

or just:

```
for x in range(n-1, -1, -1):
```

These will all count down from `n-1` to `0`, inclusive.

If you're using Python 2, you can use `xrange` in place of `range` to avoid actually constructing the list.  In Python 3 you can just use `range`.